# Haskell - Use of Take and Drop to split a list into three parts

Tags: list, haskell, take, function-definition

So I've came across this function definition that takes a list (xs) and splits it into three parts as an output.

The thing is I'm having difficulty understanding it. I understand the first part which takes n of the list (xs) where n is defined as dividing the length of the list (xs) by 3. But after that I'm not sure entirly sure whats going on.

If anyone could walk me through this function that would be great.

Here is the code:

```
--SPLITS A LIST INTO THREE PARTS---------------------------------------------------------

split3 xs = (take n xs , take n (drop n xs) , drop (n*2) xs)
    where n = length xs `div` 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second part drops the first `n` elements and takes the following `n` elements.

```
[------- n -------][------- n -------][------- n -------]
^                  ^
dropped            taken by `take`    ^ dropped by `take`
```

A concrete example could be a list of `[1,2,3]`, `n == 1`.

```
take n (drop n xs)
== take 1 (drop 1 [1,2,3])
== take 1 [2,3]
== 2
```

---

The third part drops twice `n` and takes the rest

```
[----             2n            -----][---- n -----]
^                                     ^
dropped                               taken by `drop`
```

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand, in your example of [1,2,3] you drop 1 from the list first and then take 1 from that list. I'm not understanding how that works. Does that you mean litrally taking the number 1 element from the list or any single element from the list? Also on the line == take 1 [2,3] why is the result just 2?

Comment: Also could I have a more detailed explanation on this sentance "The second part drops the first n elements and takes the following n elements." It's really confusing me.

Comment: @GR412 `take 1` is a function that takes one element from the front, not the element `1`! Consider `take 2 ['a', 'b', 'c] == ['a', 'b']`. Thus the sentence simply means that the `take` in that case is called on a list that you get when you take the original list and drop `n` first elements from it. However, the remaining "tail" has 2n elements, the second 1/3 and the third 1/3, so by taking only n you get the actual middle part.